# How to set TextColor and HorizontalOptions on two side by side labels?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, layout, label

I have this label. I want to centralize and give the orange color to it, but don't know how.

```
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="R$"
                  FontAttributes="Bold"
                  FontSize="Large"/>
            <Span x:Name="CalculoParcial"
                  FontAttributes="Bold"
                  FontSize="Large"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText> 
</Label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding Backgroundcolor, HorizontalOptions and HorizontalTextAlignment?

```
<Label BackgroundColor="Orange" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="R$"
                  FontAttributes="Bold"
                  FontSize="Large"
                  />
            <Span x:Name="CalculoParcial"
                  FontAttributes="Bold"
                  FontSize="Large"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText> 
</Label>
```

Comment: No you are not.